# Retrieve percentage of total CPU usage in android 8.0

Tags: 8.0-oreo

The access to **`/proc/stat`** is disabled on Android 8.0 and the `top` command can't also be used. So I wonder if there are any solution to access the total CPU usage in android 8.0?

Comment: This question has been answered on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182041/get-cpu-usage-of-a-device-running-android-8-oreo).

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve this metric anymore :((

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit overreacting – but I wait for the day they disable any input and just let you watch ads. With each new Android version, access to something else was removed for non-root.

Comment: @Izzy Android has previously been described as a "look, don't touch" kind of open.